# How to set selected value on Dropdown on Angular

Tags: angular

I created a form to update data of branches, and branch are belong to school, then when admin try to update the branch info, he/she should find the dropdown list is selected the right school.

how can I do it with angular?

```
<div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="selectSchool" class="form-label">The branch belongs to</label>
                    <div ngbDropdown>
                      <select class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg" ngbDropdownToggle
                        (change)="changeSchool($event)"
                        
                        formControlName="school_id" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': isBranchFormSubmitted && form2.school_id.errors}">
                        
                        <option ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let school of schoolsFromSchoolComponent" [value]="school.id">
                          {{ school.name }}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                      <div *ngIf="isBranchFormSubmitted && form2.school_id.errors?.required" class="invalid-feedback">
                        Required
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

and here is the typescript code:

```
openVerticalCenteredModal(content: TemplateRef<any>, branch: any) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {centered: true}).result.then((result) => {
      console.log("Modal closed" + result);
    }).catch((res) => {});
    
    this.editForm.patchValue({
      name: branch.name,
      name_ar: branch.name_ar,
      address: branch.address,
      address_ar: branch.address_ar,
      number: branch.number,
      email: branch.email,
      description: branch.description,
      school_id: branch.school_id
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mistake was on the typescript
it should be like this

```
openVerticalCenteredModal(content: TemplateRef<any>, branch: any) {
this.modalService.open(content, {centered: true}).result.then((result) => {
  console.log("Modal closed" + result);
}).catch((res) => {});

this.editForm.patchValue({
  name: branch.name,
  name_ar: branch.name_ar,
  address: branch.address,
  address_ar: branch.address_ar,
  number: branch.number,
  email: branch.email,
  description: branch.description,

  // here
  school_id: branch.school.id
 });
```

}